# Telerik MVC Grid : Create custom FilterDescriptor based on lambda expression

Tags: model-view-controller, filter, grid, telerik, expression

Currently I'm using this code to create a custom filter:

```
var fName = new FilterDescriptor
{
    Member = "Name",
    MemberType = typeof(string),
    Operator = FilterOperator.Contains,
    Value = name
};
```

Which will be added to the GridCommand like this:

```
gridCommand.FilterDescriptors.Add(fName);
```

However, would like to create filters based on Linq lambda expression like:

```
IQueryable<CD> query = ...
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Artist))
{
    query = query.Where(cd => cd.Artist.Contains(Artist));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
{
    query = query.Where(cd => cd.Name.Contains(Name));
}
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the QueryableExtensions.cs file from Telerik, this extension method will do the job:

```
/// <summary>
/// Filters a sequence of values based on a collection of <see cref="IFilterDescriptor"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source">The source.</param>
/// <param name="filterDescriptors">The filter descriptors.</param>
/// <returns>
/// An <see cref="IQueryable" /> that contains elements from the input sequence
/// that satisfy the conditions specified by each filter descriptor in <paramref name="filterDescriptors" />.
/// </returns>
public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, IEnumerable<IFilterDescriptor> filterDescriptors) { }
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of this? Automatically creating the LINQ expression based on Telerik filters. I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Now I'm using https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx to convert the Telerik filter into a dynamic LINQ query

Comment: 8 years later, this is still here, and still needed sometimes. I'm in .NET Core 3.1, and almost thought it was gone. Didn't realize I needed to do `.AsQueryable()` on my list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there isnt much wrong with the way you are doing it currently. Except if you were determined to add as linq expression then use the following example.

```
var query = from t in query where t.Artist.Contains(Artist) && t.Name.Contains(Name) select t;
```

If both Artist and Name are empty or null then it will return all anyway.

Comment: What I really want to automatically create the linq expression based on the Telerik filters.